# Fido2ApiCall failed in Chromium for Android, mode = BROWSER

Tags: android, chromium, webauthn

- Checking out and building Chromium for Android (https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/refs/heads/main/docs/android_build_instructions.md)
- install and run Chromium for Android
- navigate https://webauthn.io
- enter any username
- press Register button

```
03-09 11:48:37.073   996  2738 I vendor.qti.hardware.servicetracker@1.2-service: total connections for service : com.google.android.gms/.chimera.GmsBoundBrokerServiceare :1
03-09 11:48:37.073   996  2738 I vendor.qti.hardware.servicetracker@1.2-service: total connections for client : org.chromium.chromeare :5
03-09 11:48:37.074  1935  5157 D CompatibilityInfo: mCompatibilityFlags - 0
03-09 11:48:37.074  1935  5157 D CompatibilityInfo: applicationDensity - 440
03-09 11:48:37.074  1935  5157 D CompatibilityInfo: applicationScale - 1.0
03-09 11:48:37.074   996  2738 I vendor.qti.hardware.servicetracker@1.2-service: startService() is called for servicecom.google.android.gms/.chimera.GmsBoundBrokerService
03-09 11:48:37.078 30122 30122 D BoundBrokerSvc: onBind: Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.fido.fido2.privileged.START pkg=com.google.android.gms }
03-09 11:48:37.078 30122 30122 D BoundBrokerSvc: Loading bound service for intent: Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.fido.fido2.privileged.START pkg=com.google.android.gms }
03-09 11:48:37.079  2895  6467 I SarService: Receiver polling >>>> Change receiver mode: off
03-09 11:48:37.086 30122 30448 E Fido    : [FidoBrowserApiChimeraService] Rejecting browser request from org.chromium.chrome because the hash of the certificate (32A2FC74D731105859E5A85DF16D95F102D85B22099B8064C5D8915C61DAD1E0) is not recognised. [CONTEXT service_id=149 ]
03-09 11:48:37.089 12271 12271 E cr_Fido2Request: FIDO2 API call failed
03-09 11:48:37.089 12271 12271 E cr_Fido2Request: com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 17: API: Fido.FIDO2_PRIVILEGED_API is not available on this device. Connection failed with: ConnectionResult{statusCode=RESTRICTED_PROFILE, resolution=null, message=null}
03-09 11:48:37.089 12271 12271 E cr_Fido2Request:   at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.ApiExceptionUtil.fromStatus(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.0.1:3)
03-09 11:48:37.089 12271 12271 E cr_Fido2Request:   at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.ApiExceptionMapper.getException(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.0.1:1)
03-09 11:48:37.089 12271 12271 E cr_Fido2Request:   at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zag.zad(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.0.1:1)
03-09 11:48:37.089 12271 12271 E cr_Fido2Request:   at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zabq.zaE(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.0.1:7)
03-09 11:48:37.089 12271 12271 E cr_Fido2Request:   at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zabq.zaD(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.0.1:2)
03-09 11:48:37.089 12271 12271 E cr_Fido2Request:   at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zabq.zar(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.0.1:24)
03-09 11:48:37.089 12271 12271 E cr_Fido2Request:   at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zabq.onConnectionFailed(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.0.1:1)
03-09 11:48:37.089 12271 12271 E cr_Fido2Request:   at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zai.onConnectionFailed(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.0.1:1)
03-09 11:48:37.089 12271 12271 E cr_Fido2Request:   at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzf.zzb(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@18.1.0:2)
03-09 11:48:37.089 12271 12271 E cr_Fido2Request:   at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zza.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@18.1.0:3)
03-09 11:48:37.089 12271 12271 E cr_Fido2Request:   at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzc.zze(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@18.1.0:3)
03-09 11:48:37.089 12271 12271 E cr_Fido2Request:   at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzb.handleMessage(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@18.1.0:31)
03-09 11:48:37.089 12271 12271 E cr_Fido2Request:   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
03-09 11:48:37.089 12271 12271 E cr_Fido2Request:   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:236)
03-09 11:48:37.089 12271 12271 E cr_Fido2Request:   at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
03-09 11:48:37.257   594   594 E SELinux : avc:  denied  { find } for pid=4620 uid=10199 name=tethering scontext=u:r:vendor_systemhelper_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:tethering_service:s0 tclass=service_manager permissive=0
```

Chromium for Linux work fine.
What settings need to be configured for android? Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2):

Note this line from the log:

> Rejecting browser request from org.chromium.chrome because the hash of the certificate (32A2FC74D731105859E5A85DF16D95F102D85B22099B8064C5D8915C61DAD1E0) is not recognised.

Play Services only allows recognised browsers to access the user's WebAuthn credentials.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I didn't find any mention of how this can be done. There is nothing like WebAuthn in the "APIs and Services" list.

Comment: Do you want to add a browser app to the list? I think there might be an page documenting that process but I can't find it right now. If you provide an email address I can get the process kicked off. If this is for development then I believe that fingerprint will be trusted on userdebug devices. https://flash.android.com/welcome can install such images on supported devices.

Comment: I only found https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/api-keys But I don't see anything about fido here. In the standard documentation, the android Fido2ApiCall in browser mode is not described. Tomorrow I'll try to check on userdebug phone, I hope it will works. Thank you fo help ( sergey.shpital 'at' gmail.com )

Comment: @agl Sorry for bringing up an old topic, but do you know how to add a browser to the list?

Comment: See the final paragraph on developer.android.com/training/sign-in/privileged-apps